# Mark test as skipped from pytest_collection_modifyitems

Tags: python, pytest

How can I mark a test as skipped in pytest collection process?

What I'm trying to do is have pytest collect all tests and then using the `pytest_collection_modifyitems` hook mark a certain test as skipped according to a condition I get from a database.

I found a solution which I don't like, I was wondering if maybe there is a better way.

```py
def pytest_collection_modifyitems(items, config):
    ... # get skip condition from database
    for item in items:
        if skip_condition == True:
            item._request.applymarker(pytest.mark.skipif(True, reason='Put any reason here'))
```

The problem with this solution is I'm accessing a protected member (`_request`) of the class..

Comment: Why are you trying to do it that way around?

Comment: @jonrsharpe we are making a database to enable skipping tests from there and not having to commit the skip and wait for every developer to rebase to master in order for tests to pass.

Comment: But if you put the database call as part of the `skipif` when you actually decorate the method, then you'll achieve the same thing without having to retrospectively `applymarker`.

Comment: Hmm.. Didn't thought about it, but it could work.. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You were almost there. You just need `item.add_marker`

```
def pytest_collection_modifyitems(config, items):
    skip = pytest.mark.skip(reason="Skipping this because ...")
    for item in items:
        if skip_condition:  # NB You don't need the == True
            item.add_marker(skip)
```

Note that `item` has an iterable attribute `keywords` which contains its markers. So you can use that too.

See [pytest documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html#control-skipping-of-tests-according-to-command-line-option) on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over testcases (items) and skip them using a common fixture. With 'autouse=True' you shouldn't pass it in each testcase as a parameter:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='function', autouse=True)
def my_common_fixture(request):
    if True:
       pytest.skip('Put any reason here')
```